# stream - 'done event is being called even when pausing the connection'

Tags: node.js, stream, csvtojson

I am trying to read from csv and i am pausing the stream as i need to do do some async task using await. However the done event is called before the all the row has been processed. as I understand even when paused that doesn't stop the done even fron being called. Is there any workaroung to this?

```
let res = csv({
                delimiter: '|',
                // noheader: true,
                output: "csv",
                nullObject: true
            })
            .fromStream(fs.createReadStream(`./dbscvs/new_${table.name}.csv`))
            .on('data', async (data) => {
                res.pause()
                await new Promise(resolve=>{
                    setTimeout(resolve,5000)
                })
                res.resume()
            })
            .on('done', async e => {
                console.log('done')
            })
            .on('error', (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`end`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_events_finish_and_end) event, which is emitted after all data has been output.